# how to EXTRACT against a ZIP file containing multiple CSV datasets

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I understand that if we simply have 1 zip file that has 1 csv file, we can simply `EXTRACT` it:

```
DECLARE @file1 string = @"/input/input.csv.zip";

@file =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 string
    FROM @file1
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent : true);
```

However, what if we have multiple csv files in 1 zip:

```
inputfiles.zip
-file1.csv
-file2.csv
-file3.csv
```

**How do we EXTRACT / SELECT from `inputfiles.zip`?**

Answer (score 1):

U-SQL cannot do this natively.  Consider using Data Factory (eg For Each loop with child items) to extract the files first.

Having worked through this recently, the [go-to blog post](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/using-azure-data-factory-v2-activities-dynamic-content-to-direct-your-files) on this looks out-of-date, ie Azure Data Factory's Get Metadata task no longer deals with zip files.  Instead, the Copy task can do it directly.  I've tried to document the approach without using screenprints from the GUI:

[image: Data factory example added]

Comment: thank you. another one for you when you have a chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977315/how-do-we-generate-a-random-id-for-each-record

Answer (score 1):

U-SQL cannot extract it natively, but you can create your own extractor do do that.

I used that code and it works:

https://ryansimpson.net/2016/10/15/query-zipfile-adla/

Comment: A perfectly valid approach @JorgeRibeiro.  Personally I prefer to use existing components such as Data Factory as they are easier to debug than custom tasks but horses for courses : )